# Spring, What's the better way to override the member variables of parent class

Tags: spring, autowired

I have a abstract service class, which defines some shared functions, and it was set to use some autowired DAOs that would query the database1 by default:

```
public abstract class AbstractStatisticsService {

    @Autowired
    protected Table1DAO table1DAO;

    @Autowired
    protected Table2DAO table2DAO;

    public String queryTable1(){
        return table1DAO.query();
    }

    public String queryTable2(int id){
        return table2DAO.queryById(id);
    }

}
```

The question is, I want to have a service bean which extends the abstract service, but change the DAOs to some other that would query the database2.

Now I use a @PostConstruct annotation to replace the member DAOs after it was initialized:

```
public class StatisticsDb2Service extends AbstractStatisticsService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("table1DB2Dao")
    protected Table1DAO table1DAO;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("table2DB2Dao")
    protected Table2DAO table2DAO;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initOps() {
        super.table1DAO = table1DAO;
        super.table2DAO = table2DAO;
    }

    /* some exclusive codes */

}
```

It seems OK now but when it comes to a day that there are many DAOs in the abstract class, I would have to manually add codes to replace all the DAOs.

What's the better way to deal with this: easily setup the member DAOs from the parent class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use constructor-autowiring

```
public abstract class AbstractService {

    protected final Table1DAO table1DAO;
    protected final Table2DAO table2DAO;

    public AbstractService(Table1DAO table1DAO, Table2DAO table2DAO) {
        this.table1DAO = table1DAO;
        this.table2DAO = table2DAO;
    }
}

@Service
public class Db1Service extends AbstractService {

    @Autowired
    public Db1Service(
            @Qualifier("table1DB1Dao") Table1DAO table1DAO,
            @Qualifier("table2DB1Dao") Table2DAO table2DAO
    ) {
        super(table1DAO, table2DAO);
    }
}

@Service
public class Db2Service extends AbstractService {

    @Autowired
    public Db2Service(
            @Qualifier("table1DB2Dao") Table1DAO table1DAO,
            @Qualifier("table2DB2Dao") Table2DAO table2DAO
    ) {
        super(table1DAO, table2DAO);
    }
}
```